# How to wait for a millisecond

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, timer

I've tried `std::this_thread::sleep_for` and `CreateWaitableTimer`.

Both have the same effect: The thread is consistently continued after 16ms by the Windows Task Scheduler or by Billy G. himself or whatever... Losing my mind anyway. When part of a Windows App the time can vary if that App is actively worked on.

Here's the sample code, I've also thrown in some `SetThreadPriority` for good measure

```
#include <windows.h>    
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

double GetTiming(); 
void Wait();

int main()
{
    SetPriorityClass( GetCurrentProcess(), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS );
    SetThreadPriority( GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL );
    while ( true )
    {
        //DoSomething();
        Wait1ms();                                  // => 16ms
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( 1ms );     // => 16ms
        std::cout << "dt = " << GetTiming() << "\n";
    }
}

void Wait1ms()
{
    HANDLE hTimer = NULL;
    LARGE_INTEGER liDueTime;

    liDueTime.QuadPart = -10000LL;
    hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, TRUE, NULL);
    SetWaitableTimer( hTimer, &liDueTime, 0, NULL, NULL, 0 );
    auto result = ( WaitForSingleObject( hTimer, INFINITE ) != WAIT_OBJECT_0 );
}

double GetTiming()
{
    static high_resolution_clock::time_point last;
    const auto difference = high_resolution_clock::now() - last;
    last = high_resolution_clock::now();
    return difference.count() / 1000000.0;
}
```

Comment: Schedulers on things like Windows don't operate with millisecond granularity, sorry

Comment: I think by default, the clock on Windows has a 15.625ms resolution (=64 ticks per second).

Comment: Windows is not a real-time OS. You won't be able to reliably achieve 1ms precision. The closest you would get to that is running a busy loop, checking the high-resolution clock repeatedly (see `QueryPerformanceCounter` et al).

Comment: OK, how to write a "busy loop" that does not keep one core 100% busy?
It's quite funny how ppl jump in telling me something does not work when I just said it does not work...

Comment: If you need to learn something new, you will have to explain what *problem* you are trying to solve. So far, all you've shown is a solution that doesn't work to an undisclosed problem. This is called the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Well, that is easy. Just use a busy loop and query a high resolution timer. But then, apparently you do not want to burn through an entire core either (which, incidentally, isn't in the title). You're going to have to make up your mind what your *actual* requirements are. Though, I'm still confident that you're trying to solve the wrong problem altogether.

Comment: If your `DoSomeThing()` function is heavy duty graphics and such, then it probably takes more than 1ms to finish anyway. So you can just check the time at the end of the function. On the other hand, if you are making a clock which for some reason has to know to time constantly, it will have to hijack a core. So it gets back to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

The default clock interrupt is 64 times per second. You can change this to 1000 times per second using `timeBeginPeriod(1)` in `timeapi.h`.

As this has a significant affect on battery life and system load you should cancel the faster rate as soon as possible using `timeEndPeriod(1)`.

Older Windows and some hardware may not support such a high rate you can use `timeGetDevCaps()` to read `wPeriodMin` and use that value instead of 1.

```
guTimeResolution = 0;
gbUseHiResTimer = false;
if (timeBeginPeriod(1) == TIMERR_NOERROR) {
    gbUseHiResTimer = true;
    guTimeResolution = 1;
}
else {
    // Query capabilities of the timer to find min period
    TIMECAPS tc;
    timeGetDevCaps(&tc, sizeof(tc));
    if (timeBeginPeriod(tc.wPeriodMin) == TIMERR_NOERROR) {
        guTimeResolution = tc.wPeriodMin;
        gbUseHiResTimer = true;
    }
}
```

Then later

```
if (gbUseHiResTimer) {
    timeEndPeriod(guTimeResolution);
    gbUseHiResTimer = false;
}
```

NOTE: It seems that behaviour has changed somewhat on Windows 11 and this may not work if, quote, "*a window-owning process becomes fully occluded, minimized, or otherwise invisible or inaudible to the end user, Windows does not guarantee a higher resolution than the default system resolution*". Which sort of makes sense as the functions are intended for use with multimedia programs.

Comment: You need not worry about older Windows versions or hardware. It's newer versions of Windows that are at risk of ignoring the request (as the documentation for [`timeBeginPeriod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod) explains).

Comment: @Dipstick The Windows 11 feature of falling back to default 64Hz if the App is in the background is indeed annoying. Any ideas how to prevent that?

Comment: @non-user38741 Unfortunately I don't, but may need to investigate when I get back to work after the holidays as it could be affecting a program I maintain that has been working fine for decades but struggles on Windows 11.

Comment: I'm investigating... On minimize it always goes to 64Hz, but even with the window open Win11 seems to decide my App is not worth it after a while. I'll try putting on a bit of load next - maybe constantly writing to a log file

Comment: @non-user38741
Unfortunately I have been busy on other things. Have you tried using the following as well:
 `SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED);`

Comment: Makes no difference. I have had success with the following 'trick' though: Create an overlay window with `CreateWindowExA( WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED /*...*/ )` and attach it to my window (or another existing window). Admittedly weird for most use cases, but it might fit for mine. Annoyingly that window also shows in the taskbar and for Alt-Tab